Memoir: when printing pagenotes, an extra newline is added after the pagenote number
I’m using Memoir class (v3.7.19). When inserting an endnote, if I add a newline [edit: or a space] in my tex file after the opening brace, like this:
\pagennote{
text}

Then an extra newline is added between the pagenote number and its text.
But when I insert a footnote with the same newline after the opening brace:
\footnote{
text}

Then no newline is added.
Is it an inconsistency or am I missing something ? This behaviour seems undocumented in Memoir manual.
For example, with this .tex file
\documentclass{memoir}
\makepagenote

\begin{document}
An endnote\pagenote{text of an endnote}.

Another endnote\pagenote{
text of another endnote}.

A footnote\footnote{
text of footnote}.

\printpagenotes

\end{document}

The footnote is displayed like this:

and the endnotes like that:


Welcome to TeX.SE!

Pagenotes and footnotes are not handled the same way, have a look in the generated page note file, especially if there is more than one word (spaces are converted into new lines since else we can easily end with lines in the files being too long). We probably need to see if we could ignore it at the start.

@daleif I had a look a the .ent file, there is indeed an newline in it before the text of the endnote. It ends in the same way if I add an extra space (instead of a newline) after the opening brace of the \pagenote{} command – I edited my post and mentioned it.

If you just want to get rid of the \newline, use \pagenote{% (in fact, always add a % when a line ends with a brace).  If you actually want to add a space, try \hbox{ }.

People that uses endnotes often do so because the write very long tests in the notes. TeX actually have a limit to how long input lines can be (AFAIK no limit on the length of a file), so LaTeX will croak if one of these essay notes are longer than this particular limit. To fix it, in memoir when the page note is written to the .ent file, we mess with space, and make it into a new line (blank lines are already converted into \par at this point). This is usually not a problem unless one have a tendency to start your macros with a space or newline, as this now ens up as a blank line in the .ent file, aka a new paragraph. The typesetting code was not expecting that.
On a modern LaTeX kernel, we can mess about a bit and actually automatically remove spaces at either end of an argument.
\makeatletter
\NewCommandCopy\Foobar@wrpnote \m@m@wrpnote
% add space trimmer to \m@m@wrpnote
\RenewDocumentCommand\m@m@wrpnote{ O{} >{\TrimSpaces}m }
{
  \Foobar@wrpnote[#1]{#2}
}
\makeatother

